# Cypress does not always executes click on element

Tags: javascript, testing, automated-tests, cypress

I am automating Google Calculator. 
And from time to time Cypress is not able to execute click on button.
The tests click on buttons (0 to 9 ) and do some simple math operations.
And in 30% chance it can not click on element and the test will fail.

I also recorded a video when issue appears.

[Video here](https://vimeo.com/user87137353/review/279153050/bfd1c8ff7a)

My Project is located here: 
https://github.com/afiliptsov/test-project

```
To run the test run : "npm run test:e2e:functional"
```

I tried to use different locator. Initially i was using just ID ex(#cwbt15 ) but after i made more specific locator ( **#cwbt15 > .cwbtpl > .cwbts**) and still having same issue.

Does anyone knows why it happens and how to avoid such behavior?

The project structure is :

- **cypress/PageObject.js** - place where all elements declared.
- **cypress/support/commands.js** - place where function click created and
  verification of value getting updated.
- **cypress/integration/functional/delete.spec.js** - test which was on the
  video

Comment: I made more research and it seems similar issue:
https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/695

Answer (score 46, accepted):

For those who are using cypress version `"6.x.x"` and above

You could use `{ force: true }` like:

```
cy.get("YOUR_SELECTOR").click({ force: true });
```

but this might not solve it ! **The problem might be more complex**, that's why check below

**My solution:**

```
cy.get("YOUR_SELECTOR").trigger("click");
```

**Explanation:**

In my case, I needed to watch a bit deeper what's going on. I started by pin the `click` action like this:

[image]

Then watch the console, and you should see something like:
[image]

Now click on line `Mouse Events`, it should display a table:
[image]

So basically, when Cypress executes the `click` function, it triggers all those events but somehow my component behave the way that it is detached the moment where `click event` is triggered.

So I just simplified the click by doing:

```
cy.get("YOUR_SELECTOR").trigger("click");
```

And it worked

Hope this will fix your issue or at least help you debug and understand what's wrong.

Comment: @marcacyr I'm glad this was helpful :)

Comment: actually (nov 2021) that's the only way to make 15 clicks on a single button work (e.g. clicking next in a calendar showing months). All the other way will miss one or more clicks!

Comment: Thanks for your contribution here. I have been struggling to fix similar issue in my case

Comment: This doesn't work for me. Somewhere in between I found an answer that works for me. It triggers the mouse hover, before the click. This seems to do the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58302240/8408576

Comment: For localhost everything click is working , when we tried on test server this happen and twice working for cypress to make sure lol. Also all button in my case sometimes not work with trigger click , must click() instead of .trigger('click') sadly

Comment: Thanks @Emidomenge, this helped in debugging the issue

Comment: When clicking out the array (mouse events), there was 8 events. What does it mean actually?

Answer (score 26):

For me this code worked:

Inside your click methods add : `{ force: true }` It will make force click.

Also add: `cy.wait(150)` to **beforeEach**  or **before click where your test fails**.

**It is just workaround not a solution.**

[Link to Cypress Issue](http://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/695)

Also i saw this alternative:

```
cy.get('#query-btn').invoke('width').should('be.gt', 0)

cy.get('#query-btn').invoke('width').should('be. greaterThan', 0)
```

But it didnt work out for me. Maybe will be usefull for someone!

Comment: _Also add: cy.wait(150)_ : That is never a good idea. Cypress is based on async ideology, where wait should be implicit by querying for situations like elements becoming visible, etc.

Comment: I agree but in my specific case nothing else worked. And there is a post where multiple people have same type of issue. And for now i didnt  found better solution. There is a url  attached in answer.

Comment: Downvoted it because:
1. cy.wait() is never a solution
2. force:true does not guarantee the click to succeed

Comment: @PraveenPandey When you downvoting, please propose a better solution. 

Cypress is pretty new tool, and sometimes bad solution is better than no solution.

Comment: There may be a race between the control showing up in the DOM, click event dispatch and another render bouncing it again. Browsers aren't perfect at this. I experience a 100% pass on local headless run, then 95% failure in CI pipeline where the machine is slower. On a button click. It would be best to have an ideal and sturdy await point but sometimes a wait will get you unblocked. +1

Comment: For me neither `force` or the accepted answer wored. Somewhere in between I found an answer that works. It triggers the mouse hover, before the click. This seems to do the trick: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58302240/8408576

Answer (score 19):

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/2928  helped me.

```
cy.get('[data-qa="select_workers-list"]'.contains('+ New Worker').trigger('mouseover').click();
```

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, but this is the only answer that got my script working consistently

Comment: this worked for me too, for some reason it needs `.trigger('mouseover').` before `.click()`

Comment: Mouseover causes an implicit wait. :/ allows the rendering to settle before the click dispatch. Might not actually different that the wait() solution, just different implementation :)

Comment: In my case, no matter how much time you cy.wait(). It didn't work. This was the only working solution for me.

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot. Neither click() or clickAndWait() or trigger('click') worked before. Only mouseover and click worked.

Comment: Thank you, you save my day.
I have an e2e test that clicks on elements which execute a redirection, then I execute a go back to the previous page and if I tried to click on the same element the redirection didn't work. 
Now, with the `trigger('mouseover').click()` it works.
Thanks

Answer (score 9):

Whoever finds this problem, the official way of handling it is described here: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/22/when-can-the-test-click/

TLDR:
What @jpvantuyl said, cypress clicks the button before the onclick event is there.
The lib `cypress-pipe` will add a `.pipe` method that if followed by `.should` will retry a function until the condition is true or it times out.

Example:

```
cy
  .get(numbers.result.idLocator)
  .pipe($el => $el.click()) // try this
  .pipe(
    // next line will make assertions on the element returned by this pipe
    () => cy.get(calculatorScreen.resultOutput.idLocator)
  )
  .should("contain", "0"); // until this happens or times out
```

Answer (score 7):

Something I just learned from a colleague after none of the above worked for me and after hours of searching. Just blew my mind. Just add another .click()...

before:

```
cy.contains('some string').click();
```

In the left Cypress menu click on the action and you'll see the indicator that it clicks the correct part, but nothing happens. Do it manual in the browser and it works.

Fix:

```
cy.contains('some string').click().click();
```

and all of the sudden the string is clicked and test is moving on to the next page

Comment: Could you please explain why it worked for you?

Answer (score 6):

This could be because the application is attaching behaviors to the button via JavaScript.  When that script takes a long time to execute it allows Cypress to click the button *before* the OnClick event is there.

See: https://www.cypress.io/blog/2018/02/05/when-can-the-test-start/

Cypress recommends tracking when the underlying JS is in place with something like:

```
function waitForAppStart() {
  // keeps rechecking "appHasStarted" variable
  return new Cypress.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const isReady = () => {
      if (appHasStarted) {
        return resolve()
      }
      setTimeout(isReady, 0)
    }
    isReady()
  })
}
it('greets', () => {
  cy.visit('app.html', {
    onBeforeLoad: spyOnAddEventListener
  }).then(waitForAppStart)
  // all other assertion will run only when
  // the application has started
  cy.get('#name').type('Cypress{enter}')
  cy.contains('#answer', 'Cypress')
})
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case I had to make sure the button is visible(or not disabled), then mouseover, then click:

```
 cy.contains(/activate/i)
  .should('be.visible')
  .trigger('mouseover')
  .click({ force: true });
```

PS. `/***/i` means ignore letter case.

Answer (score 2):

I found that my button's event listeners were loaded but the button was not receiving the focus it needed. It was definitely clickable. I tried using the `cypress-pipe` package but to no avail. So, instead of invoking `.click()` on it 2 or more times, I ensured it was first set in focus prior to being clicked. This fixed it for me.

```js
cy.get('button').focus().click()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why, but for me this worked:

```
cy.get('[role="button"][aria-haspopup="listbox"]').trigger('mouseover').wait(1000).click().click({force:true});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've worked through many of the answers posted above and it was https://stackoverflow.com/a/70932275/19377357 that gave me the first solution that worked. I stripped each section away to see what was necessary and what wasn't.

Apparently, all the page needed (that I was working on) was a second to load:

`cy.get('YOUR-SELECTOR').wait(1000).click();`

Comment: Do you realize `cy.get('YOUR-SELECTOR')` already waits for 4 seconds?

Comment: But a hard wait is different to a timeout - although `cy.get()` has *timeout* of 4 seconds, it may return an element in much less time that that. But if the event handler has not yet loaded, the click will not succeed - see [when-can-the-test-click](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2019/01/22/when-can-the-test-click).

Answer (score 0):

FWIW: I was having problems submitting/navigating after a Google Places address selection. I believe my component wasn't re-rendering post-address selection.

To solve my issue, after address selection, I selected a random text element, clicked on it (no-op) and then clicked on my continue button and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

I switched my app from being rendered as SPA to using SSR (basically removing `ssr: false` from my svelte.config) which started to fail my Cypress tests. Reverting fixed it for my test setup.

Answer (score 0):

In my case one of web element was being disabled for few time and then being enabled.

Due to that .click() and .click({ force: true }) was not helping to perform the click operation.

Tried:

cy.get('daterange').trigger("click"); -It worked. You can try too.

Answer (score 0):

if nothing of those works for you :

```
     cy.get('#fileUpload').trigger('mousedown').trigger('mouseup');
     cy.get('#fileUpload').click({ force: true });
     cy.get('#fileUpload').invoke('click');
```

try using the 'realClick' event from [this](https://github.com/dmtrKovalenko/cypress-real-events) package

```
     cy.get('#fileUpload').realClick();
```

this worked for me.